# Laravel whats Token in reset password which that required

Tags: php, laravel

when in implementing reset password, i get this error after send form:

```
The token field is required.
```

I'm not sure whats that, because i have `{{ csrf_field() }}` in form

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Auth', 'middleware' => 'throttle:5:15'], function () {
    $this->get('/page/login', 'LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
    $this->post('/page/login', 'LoginController@login');
    $this->get('/page/logout', 'LoginController@logout')->name('logout');
    $this->get('/page/register', 'RegisterController@showRegisterForm');
    $this->post('/page/register', 'RegisterController@register');

// Password Reset Routes...
    $this->get('/page/password/reset', 'ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.request');
    $this->get('/page/password/reset/{token}', 'ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset');
    $this->post('/page/password/email', 'ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.email');
    $this->post('/page/password/reset', 'ResetPasswordController@reset');
});
```

Url to reset password that i get that from sent mail

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/page/password/reset/0ebc929e67b6f595be60d290b9bc76c56702998bf45c177d489d6ceb4e615deb
```

and my form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ route('password.request') }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    ...
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `action=` is right (it could be `{{ route('password.reset') }}`)

Then try to add this to your form
`<input type="hidden" name="token" value="{{ $token }}">`
or in laravel 5.6
`@csrf`